# Business Logic Between 2+ Models in Django rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've read a lot about this, but I still can't get to the bottom of how to implement it. I'm new into Python/Django programming and I'm making an application with DRF+PostgreSQL.

All good, I'm making basic post/get operations which basically return the models as they are, no business logic or data treatments between.

My complication now is that I need to build a "custom response" with business logic and I don't know how to do it or where to implement it, for example, I have these models:

```
class Parking(models.Model):
address = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='address')
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class ParkingLot(models.Model):        
    parking = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='parkinglots')
    floor = models.IntegerField(null=False)

class ParkingAvailability(models.Model):
    parkinglot = models.ForeignKey(ParkingLot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='availability')
    available = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False)
```

if I return a Parking, I get all the other models in the response(parkinglot and availability), which is fine. Now, I want to return the address of the parking, but just the total of the ParkingLots that meet x conditions, for example: number of parkinglots that the floor is 4 and that are available.

1. Where should I implement this? I've read about a service or manager file that implement these types of business conditions but some people say that's not a good idea.
2. How should I implement it? I have to make queries to those models in order to (for example) get the parkinglots of one Parking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with name **views.py** where you will put business logic and a file named **urls.py** where you will define different urls which will redirect to the logic written in the **views.py** file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think i put more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704579/how-can-i-add-multiple-models-and-custom-fields-to-a-json-response-in-django-res